# How do I use BeautifulSoup to extract all the news article urls from this webpage - https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Noob trying to work on a news aggregation mini assignment using python.I use VSCode.
I'm at the step where i'm supposed to grab all the news article urls from this link -  https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/

This is the basic code which is giving me every single link, but I only need the news article urls pls help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://indianexpress.com/section/technology/')
bSoup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links_list = bSoup.find_all('a')

for link in links_list:
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(str(link.attrs['href']) + "\n")
```

Comment: theres lots of ways to do this, you could use bs4 to navigate to the div containing the articles, but the simplest way is to do what you did, but just filter on `link.attr['href'].startswith('https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/')`

Comment: Just add `and 'article/' in link.attrs['href']` or `and link.attrs['href'].startswith('https://indianexpress.com/article/')` to your `if`

Comment: i'm sorry but im very bad at this, i don't understand how the final code will look like based on your solutions. can you just paste the code with the modification?

Comment: its returning True False True False True false as the output when i do     print(str(link.attrs['href'].startswith('https://indianexpress.com/article/')) + "\n")

Comment: @psico we meant use it as a CONDITION, not the actual output. Like `if 'href' in link.attrs and 'article/' in link.attrs['href']:....`

Comment: okay, will do that. thanks.

Comment: @psico your print statement was fine. Expect booleans to be meant for conditions most of the time; and also, I had `and` in my suggestion , which should have been another indication

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the links so that only the ones containing `article/` remain. (Python's [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) is my favorite syntax for filtering.)

A possible solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://indianexpress.com/section/technology/')
bSoup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links_list = bSoup.find_all('a')

#filter links for articles:
article_links_all = [
    l.get('href') for l  in links_list 
    if 'href' in l.attrs and 'article/' in l.attrs['href']
]

# get rid of duplicates:
article_links = list(set(article_links_all))

for link in article_links:
    print(link)
```

Then the output will be:

```
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/mobile-tabs/older-apple-ipads-to-get-stage-manager-support-with-ipados-16-1-beta-8177892/
https://indianexpress.com/article/sports/sport-others/in-gujarat-the-national-games-garba-and-the-start-of-election-fever-8179176/
https://indianexpress.com/article/lifestyle/health/covid-may-increase-heart-ailments-if-it-becomes-endemic-expert-8179186/
https://indianexpress.com/article/lifestyle/health/patient-administer-self-cpr-heart-attack-cardiac-arrest-cardiopulmonary-resuscitation-8178675/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/google-search-new-features-multisearch-food-shopping-google-maps-8179203/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/erbium-is-a-malware-that-steals-credit-card-details-passwords-and-hacks-crypto-wallets-8177544/
https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/what-the-rajasthan-political-crisis-highlights-congress-effectively-has-no-high-command-8176760/
https://indianexpress.com/article/cities/thiruvananthapuram/home-ministry-lists-murders-and-attacks-by-pfi-cadres-in-ban-notification-8178553/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/tech-indepth-understanding-nvidia-dlss-and-dlss-3-8178684/
https://indianexpress.com/article/horoscope/horoscope-today-26-september-2022-check-astrological-prediction-for-scorpio-sagittarius-cancer-aries-and-other-signs-8162319/
https://indianexpress.com/article/what-is/what-is-the-protection-of-children-from-sexual-offences-act-2012/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/apple-ditches-iphone-production-increase-after-demand-falters-8177169/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/science/ancient-armoured-bristly-worm-wufengella-phylum-evolution-lophophore-8178150/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/intel-and-samsung-display-showcase-slidable-pc-during-intels-innovation-keynote-8177212/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-reviews/realme-9i-5g-review-8159696/
https://indianexpress.com/article/sports/cricket/watch-suresh-raina-takes-a-stunner-against-australia-legends-in-road-safety-world-series-semi-8179194/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/techook/amazon-flipkart-sales-best-budget-tws-earbuds-to-buy-under-rs-3000-8177816/
https://indianexpress.com/article/entertainment/bollywood/ranbir-kapoor-trade-decodes-the-stars-box-office-journey-the-good-the-bad-the-blockbuster-8176244/
https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/editorials/after-the-ban-the-political-challenge-posed-by-pfi-still-needs-tackling-8179138/
https://indianexpress.com/article/india/code-of-ethics-for-digital-news-websites-6758543/
https://indianexpress.com/article/sports/cricket/chahar-arshdeep-send-back-half-sa-side-in-15-balls-as-india-secure-victory-in-first-t20i-8179221/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/amazons-big-september-2022-echo-event-tonight-heres-what-to-expect-8177264/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/mobile-tabs/nothing-phone-1-gets-another-camera-centric-update-8178907/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/techook/nova-to-niagara-the-top-android-launchers-to-try-out-on-your-smartphone-8175729/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/science/italian-space-agency-releases-liciacube-images-of-dart-crash-8177728/
https://indianexpress.com/article/explained/pfi-terrorist-organisation-mha-ban-explained-8177409/
https://indianexpress.com/article/cities/delhi/delhi-ncr-news-live-updates-rains-aap-arvind-kejriwal-bjp-8173016/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-reviews/oppo-enco-buds-2-review-8153028/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/intel-announces-13th-gen-intel-core-processor-heres-everything-you-need-to-know-8177290/
https://indianexpress.com/article/sports/cricket/ind-vs-sa-1st-t20-surya-woke-up-after-he-got-hit-8179164/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-reviews/vivo-v25-pro-review-8177339/
https://indianexpress.com/article/trending/trending-in-india/rhinoceros-walks-on-nepal-road-unmindful-of-people-touching-it-8178819/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/gaming/netflix-launches-game-handles-for-its-games-all-you-need-to-know-8178368/
https://indianexpress.com/article/india/senior-advocate-r-venkataramani-is-new-attorney-general-of-india-8179072/
https://indianexpress.com/article/cities/delhi/delhi-yamuna-flowing-warning-level-heavy-rain-basin-states-8173217/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/amazons-september-2022-product-launch-event-announcements-8179069/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-reviews/samsung-galaxy-watch-5-pro-review-8151008/
https://indianexpress.com/article/entertainment/movie-review/blonde-movie-review-ana-de-armas-imarilyn-monroe-biopic-netflix-8175733/
https://indianexpress.com/article/business/economy/rupee-value-us-dollar-falls-low-news-8173192/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/gadgets/sony-india-festive-sale-deals-discounts-on-audio-headphones-tws-speakers-tvs-8178107/
https://indianexpress.com/article/trending/trending-in-india/women-perform-garba-inside-mumbai-local-train-8178884/
https://indianexpress.com/article/india/jaishankar-sullivan-discuss-bilateral-ties-indo-pacific-8179191/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/dating-apps-thrive-in-china-but-not-just-for-romance-8177218/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/science/nasa-spacex-crew-5-launch-dragon-endurance-falcon-9-8178453/
https://indianexpress.com/article/cities/ahmedabad/two-firs-lodged-over-clashes-between-nsui-abvp-members-8179172/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/science/how-about-them-apples-research-orchards-chart-a-fruits-future-8178701/
https://indianexpress.com/article/cities/baroda/borsad-municipality-president-loses-no-confidence-motion-as-bjp-members-defy-party-whip-8179197/
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-reviews/viewsonic-xg2431-gaming-monitor-review-8140688/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).